# How to properly import the BaseGameUtils library into Eclipse?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to import the BaseGameUtils library into Eclipse from this GitHub repository: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples.

Following the instructions provided, I attempted to import it as a project using the following steps:

1. Go to `File` > `Import`.
2. Choose `General` > `Existing Projects into Workspace`.
3. Select the root directory, which in my case is `...\android-basic-samples-master\BasicSamples\libraries\BaseGameUtils`.

However, Eclipse is giving me the message "No projects are found to import."

Can someone guide me on how to correctly import the BaseGameUtils library into Eclipse? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: have you imported the google play games services library from eclipse's SDK manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select "import existing android code in to workspace" not "import existing project in to workspace"